# Rendering html with data with nodejs Express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm new to express framework i just want know how to render html page with some data from mongo DB i used below code to send html but not sure how to send some data

```
res.sendFile(path + "feature.html"); this is success as html get renders
```

send data like this ??

```
res.sendFile(path + "feature.html", {data: data});
```

how to display  data in html ?? if i have sent an array like this

```
res.sendFile(path + "feature.html", {data: []});
```

how to loop this in html ??

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest you to use some template engine, like [ejs](https://github.com/tj/ejs) or [jade](http://jade-lang.com/). This form, you can use [res.render](http://expressjs.com/pt-br/api.html) and send json information for view. For more details consult the engine docs and `res.render` doc too.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to render an html page on node.js express, you need to install any of the template engine like ejs or jade and set the view directory. 
The code used to install ejs using npm is,

```
npm install ejs --save
```

include the following code into your app.js file will resolve your problem.

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extend:true}));
app.engine('html', require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', __dirname);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.render("index");
});
```

Comment: After edit this line `app.set('view engine', 'html');` to `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` running fine.

Comment: It's better if you added that "how data passed via render".